# Deterministicaly stops winning, yet if conditioned on time there is positive probability to win in the future.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, intuition, probability-limit-theorems, borel-cantelli-lemmas

In the answer to question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12462/limsup-and-liminf-for-a-sequence-of-sets "has2" gives a concrete example for the use of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ in form of a "card game". I quote the example below. What I ask is unrelated to the original question, and here it is:

Intuitively, how can it be that there, deterministically, is a time after which the player in the game stops winning. Yet, conditioned at any point in time (i.e. step $n$ of the game) there is always positive probability to win in the future?

I can not, intuitively, settle those two facts together, is there any re-phrasal of those two statements which makes (more) evident they do not contradict one another?

---

> Here is a conceptual game that can be partially understood using these concepts: We have a deck of cards, on the face of each card an integer is printed; thus the cards are $\{1,2,3...\}$. At the nth round of this game, the first $n^2$ cards are taken, they are shuffled. You pick one of them. If your pick is $1$, you win that round. Let $A_n$ denote the event that you win the nth round. The complement $A^c_n$ of $A_n$ will represent that you lose the $n$-th round. The event $\limsup A_n$ represents those scenarios in which you win infinitely many rounds. The complement of this event is $\liminf A^c_n$, and this represents those scenarios in which you ultimately lose all of the rounds. By the Borel Cantelli Lemma $P(\limsup A_n) =0$ or equivalently $P(\liminf A^c_n)=1$. **Thus, a player of this game will deterministically experience that there comes a time, after which he never wins**.

(emphasis added)

Comment: Similar situation: take $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$, then $U<1$ with probability $1$ and yet, for every $u<1$, $U>u$ with positive probability hence there is no $u<1$ such that $U\leqslant u$ with probability $1$. (This just puts the end of times at time $1$, if you wish.)

Comment: I thought of another problem which has somewhat similar properties, but more intuitive, and evidently has no contradiction: At each step a player tosses a fair coin, he wins when he gets heads. Before step 1, a random number $t$ is generated from $U(0,1)$ but is kept secret, at step $n>\frac{1}{t}$ the coin becomes unfair and the player only gets tails. Overall there is deterministicaly a time when the player starts loosing, yet the time is random and not know, there always is a positive chance to win in the future since the player can not know whether he has already reached the stop time .

Answer (score 1):

The positive probability of winning decreases sufficiently fast as time passes.

For example, at time 1, probability of winning is 1/2. Time 2, 1/3. Time 3, 1/4. And so on.

Of course

$$\lim H_n = \infty$$

so that is not sufficiently fast.

However, if we have 1, 1/4, 1/9, 1/16, ... that is decreasing sufficiently fast.

Of course in precise terms when we say decreasing sufficiently fast we mean that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$$

In general:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n < \infty$$

---

Your question is analogous to the [Dichotomy Paradox of Zeno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox):

> Suppose Homer wants to catch a stationary bus. Before he can get there, he must get halfway there. Before he can get halfway there, he must get a quarter of the way there. Before traveling a quarter, he must travel one-eighth; before an eighth, one-sixteenth; and so on.
>
> ...
>
> This description requires one to complete an infinite number of tasks, which Zeno maintains is an impossibility.